# how to validate form in ionic using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to use the ionic framework with angular.I want to do validation of my form on button click.Mean I need to validate all field on button click.All field are required ..I need to show an error message if a field does not fulfil the requirement. Like password minimum character 5 and maximum 10. And email validation.

could you please tell m how I will do validation.Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ktz4o031/)

```
<html ng-app="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Sign-in, Then Tabs Example</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <ion-view title="Page">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header has-footer">
        <form>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">name</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="name">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">email</span>
                <input type="email" placeholder="email">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">password</span>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password">
            </label>
        </form>
        <button class="button button-balanced button-block">check validation</button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I might be late but here's what you can do.

First of all you need to define a form (as you did) using the `ng-submit` directive so that your form can be POST to the controller.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <ion-view title="Page">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header has-footer">
        <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="$scope.login($scope.user);" novalidate>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">name</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="$scope.user.username" form-validate-after>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">email</span>
                <input type="email" placeholder="email" ng-model="$scope.user.email" form-validate-after>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">password</span>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="$scope.user.password" form-validate-after>
            </label>
        </form>
        <button class="button button-balanced button-block">check validation</button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
</body>
```

I am passing a model to my input field so I can read them later.
I've marked each input with a custom directive `form-validate-after`.

This is the directive I've created:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp', ['ionic'])
        .directive('formValidateAfter', formValidateAfter);

    function formValidateAfter() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: link
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var validateClass = 'form-validate';
            ctrl.validate = false;
            element.bind('focus', function (evt) {
                if (ctrl.validate && ctrl.$invalid) // if we focus and the field was invalid, keep the validation
                {
                    element.addClass(validateClass);
                    scope.$apply(function () { ctrl.validate = true; });
                }
                else {
                    element.removeClass(validateClass);
                    scope.$apply(function () { ctrl.validate = false; });
                }

            }).bind('blur', function (evt) {
                element.addClass(validateClass);
                scope.$apply(function () { ctrl.validate = true; });
            });
        }
    }

}());
```

this code will loop through all your input fields adding a class if it is marked as non-valid.

You need to define a css:

```
.form-validate.ng-invalid {
    border: 3px solid #cc2511;
}
.form-validate.ng-valid {
    border: none;
}
```

don't forget to add `novalidate` to your form.

> novalidate is used to disable browser's native form validation.

If you want to set a field as mandatory and define max and min lenght:

```
<input name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="$scope.user.password" required ng-minlength='5' ng-maxlength='10'>
```

If you want to see this sample in action you can check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cri1TxMFKWocQAHHNOg4?p=preview).

**UPDATE**

Another approach is to set everything in-line changing class on each label:

```
<label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : loginForm.username.$invalid && !loginForm.username.$pristine, 'no-errors' : loginForm.username.$valid}">
   ...
</label>
```

Here you have to give each field a `name` and use `ng-class` directive.

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an
>   HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes
>   to be added.

You can see it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/y5aA0cGErSrZ1r6aYOZf?p=preview).